# Angular mat-menu margin

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem with the mat-menu, I have looked all over the place but nothing is working. I'm trying to add a margin-top but this one is never supported.

**`navbar-no-mobile.component.html`**

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <button class="btn-language" mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon [ngClass]="{'flag-francais': isFrench, 'flag-english': !isFrench}"></mat-icon>
    <a lang="{{language}}">{{language}}
      <fa-icon class="chevron_white" aria-hidden="true" [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>
    </a>
  </button>
  <mat-menu class="flag-menu" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="switchToEnglish()">
      <mat-icon class="flag-english"></mat-icon>
      <span lang="english">English</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="switchToFrench()">
      <mat-icon class="flag-francais"></mat-icon>
      <span lang="français">Français</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>
```

**`navbar-no-mobile.component.scss`**

```
/deep/ .cdk-overlay-container .flag-menu {
  margin-top: 4em;
}
```

I have also tried placing the css in the overall css (`styles.scss`) and inverting `.flag-menu` with `.cdk-overlay-container` or use `::ng-deep` instead of `/deep/` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Does `margin-top` appears on the `mat-menu`? If it does, just add `display: inline-block` because `mat-menu` is by default an `inline` element and therefor the margin won't apply to it.

Comment: No, he don't appears

Comment: Try to put in the styles.scss file exactly how you have it in your component instead of inverting it. Like this `.cdk-overlay-container .flag-menu { margin-top: 4em; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for me:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container .flag-menu {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

check the stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-xruuog

If it's not working for you please create stackblitz for your code.

Comment: It's strange, I tried the same thing but it didn't work, now it works perfectly, thank you very much!